# How to export particular div as pdf without using jspdf in angular?

Tags: html, angular, pdf, jspdf

I already tried by using html2canvas with the help of jspdf. But it downloads screenshot as a pdf and i'm not able to download overflowed table. I want to download directly without using print option.